# Return hybrid property from SQLAlchemy class through JSON in Flask

Tags: python, flask, orm, flask-sqlalchemy, marshmallow

looking for some help on the following.

I am using flask_sqlalchemy on Python 3+. I have a simple User and a Training class; definitions below. I have a hybrid property on the Training class that will return a boolean indicating whether the user is subscribed to the training or not. This works like a charm when working with the Jinja template engine, as I can use "training.is_subscribed(current_user)".

```
{% if training.is_subscribed(current_user) %}
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success" disabled>Subscribed</button> You can no longer join
{% else %}
```

However, now I'm writing a API route as well and returning JSON. I'm using a simple Schema (marshmallow_sqlalchemy) to serialize the Training instance. However, when trying to add "is subscribed" I run into the error indicating that I did not pass a user. Which is true, but I'm not sure how to do that. Can you please help?

> TypeError: is_subscribed() missing 1 required positional argument: 'user'

Thanks!
Scott

**Definitions**

```
training_subscribers = db.Table('training_subscribers',
    db.Column('subscriber_id', db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('user.id')),
    db.Column('training_id', db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('training.id')))

class User(db.Model, UserMixin):

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True)

    trainings = db.relationship('Training', secondary=training_subscribers,
                        backref=db.backref('subscribers', lazy='dynamic'))  

class Training(db.Model):

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)

    @hybrid_property
    def is_subscribed(self, user) -> bool:
        return self.subscribers.filter(
            training_subscribers.c.subscriber_id == user.id).count() > 0

class TrainingSchema(SQLAlchemySchema):
    class Meta:
        model = Training
        fields = ("is_subscribed","title", "id")
```

**Code to get the JSON response**

```
@mod_trainings.route('/json/bydate/<int:year>/<int:month>/<int:day>', methods=['GET'])
@login_required
def showUpcomingTrainingsJSONByDate(year, month, day):
    trainings = trainingController.getTrainingsAtDate(year, month, day)
    training_schema = TrainingSchema(many=True)
    return jsonify(training_schema.dump(trainings))

def getTrainingsAtDate(year, month, day):
    trainings_q = db.session.query(Training).filter(extract('year', Training.starts_at)==year).filter(extract('month', Training.starts_at)==month).filter(extract('day', Training.starts_at)==day).all()
    return trainings_q
```

Answer (score 0):

`training.is_subscribed` is not actually method, but property, so not callable. It's so complicated. How it works, not calling a function but taking a function out. Then what you get when you refer `training.is_subscribed` is `is_subscribed(self, user)` itself. Therefore:

> TypeError: is_subscribed() missing 1 required positional argument: 'user'

occurred.

Well, what should we do? It's so easy. Filter data until response JSON. Rendering with `current_user` means must be able to get this from flask.

Comment: hi Akihito - thanks for your reply. not sure if i follow, could you give me an example? thanks again, Scott